Can a non-degenerate $n\times n$ Hamiltonian be specified with just $n$ real eigenvalues?
I came up with this question when I was trying to work on a QM problem that was analysing symmetries - in particular the dihedral group (in a 3 dimensional Hilbert space). The question ultimately wanted to construct the most general Hamiltonian possible that respected the dihedral symmetry of the system, and then wanted to know how many real parameters one would need to specify this Hamiltonian. My own answer to this problems turned out to be just 2 real parameters.
Irrespective of whether a system exhibits any symmetry though, any valid Hamiltonian in an $n$-dimensional Hilbert space should be diagonal in its own eigenbasis, and assuming non-degeneracy, should be specified with just $n$ real eigenvalues. However I'm not sure this line of reasoning is completely correct and wanted to know if my thinking is right!

The Hamiltonian can be written as $H=UDU^\dagger$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. So when you fix $D$, there is still the unitary $U$ left unspecified.

But the Hamiltonian is D in its own eigenbasis. As I understand it, to represent the Hamiltonian in another basis, you would need to perform a unitary transformation like the one you write. But if you're claiming that to specify the Hamiltonian you need to know both U and D, you're claiming that the number of parameters required to specify the Hamiltonian is basis dependent. That doesn't make sense to me, what am I missing?

If what you're saying is true, then the Hamiltonians $\sigma^x$ and $\sigma^z$ on a single qubit are the same.  It's true that their spectra are the same, but that's not really what we mean.  If the only operator you're ever going to care about is your particular Hamiltonian, then you're right that there's no physical content in talking about anything other than its spectrum $D$.  But when you "specify the Hamiltonian," usually you do so in a standard basis of some sort that you can use to specify, say, the initial state in your Hilbert space before you start evolving it.

Beautiful, thank you so much, that cleared things up!

No. There can be two operators with the same eigenvalues but different eigenvectors.
